# Install hang on rebooting (SCSI-disk problem)

Tags: installation, boot

After successfully installing Ubuntu 11.10 earlier this day on my laptop, I was ready to do the same at my desktop alongside with Windows.

I downloaded the newest 12.04, burned the image and booted into install. After installing, I was told to reboot. So far so good.

But when I now boot (of course without the DVD), I get some errors (?) and the booting stops. The last 3 lines are:

sd 22:0:0:0 [sdl] No caching mode page present
sd 22:0:0:0 [sdl] Assuming drive cache: writethrough
sd 22:0:0:0 [sdl] Attached SCSI disk

... and that's all.

I have tried to unplug both my external drives, and the cardreader but still no luck.

How can I solve this?

Edit: Tried Ubuntu 11.04 and also Mint; same result.

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous edit (probably from the OP):

> Problem solved. The installationprocess seems to also install to
>   external hd's, and that is what happened. Made two partitions manually
>   on one of my internal hd's, and used the pointed the installation to
>   those. BUT; I managed to place the bootloader on the same disk, so
>   that when I now want to boot into Ubuntu, I have to manually chose
>   that hd from the boot-menu in bios... Starting a new topic on that.